# Angular UI Accordion: Restrict expanding to button click in heading

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an `<accordion-heading>` tag in my accordion with a couple controls inside (inputs, buttons, etc.), but I only want the accordion to expand when one specific button is clicked. Nothing else should trigger the expand/collapse. It doesn't seem there is a way to do this.

I've tried:

Setting `is-open` to false and setting it to true in the `ng-click` of my button. Doesn't work because clicking anywhere inside the `accordion-heading` toggles this boolean.

Setting `is-disabled` to true and then setting it to false when the button is clicked. Also doesn't work, the accordion stays disabled

Wrapping ONLY my button with the `<accordion-heading>` tag. This causes the rest of the markup in my heading to part of the 'expand/collapse' detail.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution to this:

In the controller `$scope.toggleOpen = false;`

In your view `is-open == toggleOpen` and on the specific button add `ng-click="$parent.toggleOpen = !$parent.toggleOpen"`

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wByMeIM3UwHyxyIAcVWB?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, you can put `:"ng-click" => "$event.stopPropagation()"` on every tag that you don't want activating the accordion

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I need, but for some reason this approach doesn't work in Angular 1.3.11, which is the version I'm using:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Vkei6uBHjlcZA6NpWkOq?p=preview

Comment: Make sure that on the other elements in your heading that you've set an ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" on them or the click will toggle the accordion-group.

+1 to miahabdu, the $parent.<variable> is exactly what I needed!